# avoid following dash in grep results

Tags: grep

I am trying to select the line that has the name "paul" in it.

```
!grep -w '^paul' some_file
```

This also returns the lines starting with **paul-henri**. How do I select the single line that starts with the word 'paul' only?

(In other words, dash - or slash / and dot . are getting selected if followed by the word paul)

---

Update:

Thanks to Tim, this worked:

```
grep -w '^paul' some_file | grep -vE 'paul[-./?]'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could match on the pattern `^paul[^-]`:

```
!grep -w '^paul[^-]' some_file
```

This would match any line starting with `paul`, which is then followed by one or more characters other than dash.  If you need to also match possible lines starting with *and* containing only `paul`, then you might need to use a negative lookahead:

```
^paul(?!-)
```

But, this would require an extended version of `grep`, and your version of grep might not support it.